# GHC can't import the standard library as long as a package environment file exists

Tags: ghc, cabal-install

When I install things with cabal-install, it automatically creates a `~/.ghc/x86_64-freebsd-8.8.3/environments/default` with a bunch of stuff in it; this allows me to import my installed packages, but takes away my ability to import the standard library, even the Prelude:

```
gtk.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Prelude’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘base-4.13.0.0’.
    You can run ‘:set -package base’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | 
  | ^
```

(It used to give me this error pointing to the first character of line 1 when line 1 was an unrelated import, so I put a blank line at the start of the file to see if it would still point the error there if there was nothing there. It does.)

If I delete the `~/.ghc/x86_64-freebsd-8.8.3/environments/default`, I can import base again but not the installed packages. I need to give it the Cabal database with `-package-db` on the command line.

While that apparently works, I think there must be a way to configure that environment file to do this automatically. But as long as `~/.ghc/x86_64-freebsd-8.8.3/environments/default` even exists, the entire standard library, including Prelude, is rendered hidden, and I can't compile anything at all (even an empty file fails with the above error). Including `global-package-db` in the environment file also didn't affect it.

Other info: I am not using Cabal to build because a .cabal file and a Setup.hs are added complexity I shouldn't need to compile a one-file throwaway program. I also tried installing the packages with `--global` passed to `cabal install`, but it still didn't install them globally.

OS: FreeBSD 12.1
GHC: 8.8.3
cabal-intsall: 3.0.2.0

Comment: Did you add `base-...` to the `build-depends`?

Comment: What `build-depends`? Isn't that a package.cabal variable?